# How make signature that expires after some time

Tags: web3js, etherscan, signature

I am working on something where i need to create a signature that will expire after some time.

Comment: I would like to help, but could you add a bit more info on your issue. From what I understood, you want a private key that will expire after some time? (A signed transaction that will be invalid after a certain period of time?)

Comment: Like I want to create any signature but it will have life span that it will be valid for 10 days.

Comment: Will that signature/private key be used to interact with smartContracts in any way?

Comment: yes, but I also want to expire it, when it's used once it cannot be useable after that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Let say i have a smart contract in which use can place order with some price. signature will be created for order. but when hi will come again and try to do same order his signature must be created new. that he can not use previous  signature to buy something new.

Answer (score 1):

A signature is basically a message which you sign with your private key. There is no "native" way to set an expiry date for a signature, so we have to think of something else.

The only way to 'expire' a signature is to add a timestamp in the message itself. By signing the message, you indicate that you accept the message contents to be used until the timestamp (expiry). If someone attempts to use the message after the timestamp, it's trivial for anyone to prove that the action is not valid, since the timestamp has passed.

This is a not trivial to implement, and how well this works depends on the context. For example if the message is used directly in a smart contract, it's easy to add a check that an expired message can not be used.

Comment: So how we can make signature like to be use only once. It cannot be useable for second time.

Comment: Please post a new questions if you have a new question

Comment: its related to signature expiry but in different scenario.

Comment: @HussamMustafa since you wont open a new question for it, I'll give the shortest answer I can: nonces

Answer (score 1):

Alright.

I think I understand your requirements.
You want a signature that will expire after some time (or after a specific number of uses)

Every signature is based on a private key (If we are talking about ETH blockchain)

Therefore you can have a smart contract that will accept interaction with a user owning a specific private key. However, you can program a smart contract to accept calls from the said user for a specific amount of time, or a fix number of uses (or any combination of thereof)

ShortAnswer: Yes, you can program smartContract to accept/decline calls from a specific private key based on pre-set conditions such as time or number of calls.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have created Signature Using Expiry Time at https://polygonscan.com/address/0x83de6119879f3acba303137f03abf42a15cf2498

Comment: Link only answer are discouraged. It is better to include the main idea in the answer and only use the link to expand the details.